# PHP date math years vs days

Tags: php

I inherited this code so I am sure there is a better way to do date math.  I'm trying not to refactor code unless I have to.

Why are these values different?

```
echo date("l, F j, Y",strtotime(date("2016-01-09")."+365 days"));
echo "<br>";
echo date("l, F j, Y",strtotime(date("2016-01-09")."+1 year"));
echo "<br>";
```

Output:

```
Sunday, January 8, 2017
Monday, January 9, 2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [2016 is a leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). It contains 366 days, not 365.

Comment: LOL You answered in less than 1 minute.  I'll come back in a few minutes when SO will allow me to accept your answer.